# React.js renderのないクラス定義

Tags: reactjs

下のＵＲＬでどうやってローソク足が描画されているのか調べています。 
CandlestickSeriesコンポーネントがそれを担っていると思いますが、CandlestickSeries内でrenderされたGenericChartComponentにrenderが定義されていません。では、GenericChartComponentの返り値は何になるのでしょうか？
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rrag/react-stockcharts-examples2/tree/master/examples/CandleStickChart

```
class CandlestickSeries extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderSVG = this.renderSVG.bind(this);
    this.drawOnCanvas = this.drawOnCanvas.bind(this);
}
drawOnCanvas(ctx, moreProps) {
    drawOnCanvas(ctx, this.props, moreProps);
}
renderSVG(moreProps) {
    const { className, wickClassName, candleClassName } = this.props;
    const { xScale, chartConfig: { yScale }, plotData, xAccessor } = moreProps;

    const candleData = getCandleData(this.props, xAccessor, xScale, yScale, plotData);

    return <g className={className}>
        <g className={wickClassName} key="wicks">
            {getWicksSVG(candleData)}
        </g>
        <g className={candleClassName} key="candles">
            {getCandlesSVG(this.props, candleData)}
        </g>
    </g>;
}

render() {
    const { clip } = this.props;
    return <GenericChartComponent
        clip={clip}
        svgDraw={this.renderSVG}
        canvasDraw={this.drawOnCanvas}
        canvasToDraw={getAxisCanvas}
        drawOn={["pan"]}
    />;
}
```

}

以下genericChartComponent
https://github.com/rrag/react-[stockcharts/blob/master/src/lib/GenericChartComponent.js](https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts/blob/master/src/lib/GenericChartComponent.js)

genericChartComponentは初期化とメソッド定義のみで何も返さず終了するように見えます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

genericChartComponentの定義を見ると、

```
class GenericChartComponent extends GenericComponent {
    ....
}
```

となっています。この`extends GenericComponent`というのは、`GenericChartComponent`クラスは`GenericComponent`を**継承**するクラスであるという宣言です。

よって、`GenericChartComponent`クラスは自身で宣言したメソッドの他に、`GenericComponent`で宣言されているメソッドを持っています。

[`GenericComponent`の定義](https://github.com/rrag/react-stockcharts/blob/master/src/lib/GenericComponent.js#L27)を見てみると378行目に`render`が定義されていますから、`GenericChartComponent`もこの`render`を使用して描画されることになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。は避けてくださいとあるのですが、お礼を言うところがわからないのでこちらから失礼します。クラスに慣れていないので助かりました。ありがとうございました。